# Unable to load theme by specified key

Tags: magento2

I registered a theme but then I deleted it. I want to get default luma theme back online as it was before but Magento 2 is still trying to get that theme that I registered before. What should I do?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: See my answer in this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115452/magento-2-theme-giving-error-unable-to-load-theme-by-specified-key-yogesh-myth/219846#219846

Comment: I tried it but still cannot get the result.