# Magento 2 : Unable to load theme by specified key

Tags: magento2, theme

I am facing the error some page of frontend.
I have tried all solution but issue is still there.

[image]

tried [Magento 2 theme giving error Unable to load theme by specified key: 'Yogesh/mytheme'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115452/magento-2-theme-giving-error-unable-to-load-theme-by-specified-key-yogesh-myth/219846#219846).

please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please check*

> - ***theme***
> - ***core_config_data*** *table for theme entry*
> - ***eav_attribute***
> - ***catalog_product_entity_varchar***
> - ***catalog_category_entity_varchar***
> - ***cms_page***
> - ***design_change***

*for assign theme to products,categories,cms pages, custom design.*

Comment: thanks for the answer.
eav_attribute, catalog_product_entity_varchar, catalog_category_entity_varchar
these 3 tables worked for me.

Comment: @DimplePanchal Great

Comment: plz vote my question :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in core_config_data contain wrong active theme.

Try to find

> select * from core_config_data  where path like '%theme%';

and check that theme exist into theme table if not then try to change theme id and check it

Comment: no I have already checked that. see the link I have shared in my question.