# Magento 2.3: Theme issue after migration

Tags: magento2, theme, migration, magento2.3.4

Magento migration from magento 1.9.2.3 to magento 2.3.3 theme error => There is no **default/theme327k** inside **core_config_data**. How to solve the error.

Following tutorial : https://bssthemes.com/blog/unable-to-load-theme-by-specified-key/#Using_SSH

[image]

How to set default **Luma** theme?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115455/85907

Comment: try this DELETE FROM theme WHERE `theme_path` LIKE 'Vendor/module';

Comment: @MohitPatel  fyi    https://snipboard.io/OWT69y.jpg

Comment: follow above my link ...

Comment: @MohitPatel As per your link already my type  = 0, still getting the issue.

Comment: in above your screenshot last all filed null https://prnt.sc/sujvfe. And What is filed ???

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/295857/85907 --- this is same action in admin panel

Comment: @MohitPatel After completed all the steps and run > php bin/magento setup:upgrade getting following error https://justpaste.it/4z0xv

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236429/85907

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108968/discussion-between-zus-and-mohit-patel).